# How can I use Perl's Test::Deep::cmp_deeply without increasing the test count?

Tags: perl, testing

It looks like [`Test::Deep`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Deep) was inspired by [`is_deeply`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Simple/lib/Test/More.pm#Complex_data_structures). My question is how do I make `cmp_deeply` part of a test instead of a test on its own? Because my list of tests only states 8, but everytime I use `cmp_deeply`, it counts as a test, making my actual number of tests 11 (because I call `cmp_deeply` 3 times) when I only have 8 functions.  I do not want to increase the number of my tests. Is there a more viable solution?

Comment: Why don't you want to increase your test count? You are already increasing your number of tests if you like that or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `eq_deeply` instead:

> This is the same as `cmp_deeply()`
>   except it just returns true or false.
>   It does not create diagnostics...

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though does it? Whether or not there is output, the number of tests would be the same between eq_deeply and cmp_deeply.

Comment: No, `eq_deeply` *just returns true or false.* It doesn't report anything to the test harness.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you can do, but without knowing more of the specifics in your tests it is difficult to know which is the most appropriate:

- Don't plan for a specific number of tests.

  ```
  use Test::More;

  all(
      cmp_deeply($got0, $expected0),
      cmp_deeply($got1, $expected1),
      cmp_deeply($got2, $expected2)
     );

  # ... your other 7 tests
  done_testing();  # signals that we're all done.. exiting normally.
  ```
- Dynamically determine how many tests are being run, which makes sense if you are testing some deep and dynamic structure whose complexity (and number of tests required) is not known in advance:

  ```
  use Test::More;
  use Test::Deep;

  # perhaps this is in some sort of loop?
  cmp_deeply($got0, $expected0);  $numTests++;
  cmp_deeply($got1, $expected1);  $numTests++;
  cmp_deeply($got2, $expected2);  $numTests++;

  # ... your other 7 tests

  # TAP output must be either at the beginning or end of all output
  plan tests => $numTests + 7;

  # no more tests here!
  exit;
  ```