# How to know two hash data are same or not-- fastest approach

Tags: perl, md5sum

I get getting data as a hash from some source at two different times. I need to know whether both hashes are the same or not. I do not need to know which key-value pairs differ.

I am thinking of storing the md5sum of the hash using Digest::MD5 module in some place (such as a database) and then compare if next received hash's md5sum is same as previous stored md5sum or not. If it is not same then data in hash differs.

My hash size is not very big max 50 keys in single hash. Is there any other better and faster approach in perl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273616/how-do-i-compare-two-hashes-in-perl-without-using-datacompare

Comment: @mpapec - How the methods described there are better and faster?

Comment: Can't tell since I didn't see your solution.

Comment: Are the two hashes in the same process or not?

Comment: Are the values always strings?

Answer (score 1):

For such a small dataset there is no need to overoptimize things.

You could use Data::Compare:

```
use Data::Compare;
print 'structures of \%h and \%v are ',
   Compare(\%h, \%v) ? "" : "not ", "identical.\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the two hash variables are in separate processes.

Hashes (e.g. md5sums) aren't guaranteed to be unique for two different texts. You need to follow with a full text compare to be sure.

Hashes are useful if you're going to compare members of a large set as it reduces the number of times you need to do a full text compare. It's just a waste of time if you just have two string to compare.

Of course, if rare false positives are not a problem, then using a hash will save storage space.