# Perl - Compare two nested hash

Tags: json, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

This is my scenario, where there are 2 hashes that have been decoded from 2 JSON files.

I have 2 complex hash,

```
$hash1 = {k1=> { k11 => v1, k12 => v2}, k2 => { k21 => [v1, v2, v3] }}
$hash2 = {k1=> { k11 => v1, k12 => v2}, k2 => { k21 => [v3, v2, v1] }}
```

I want to compare these 2 hash for equality, and used Compare of Data::Compare and is_deeply of Test::More. Both do not ignore the order of the array.
I want to compare ignoring the order of array values of key 'k21'.
My App populates the array from 'keys %hash' which gives random order.
Tried 'ignore_hash_keys' of Data::Compare, but my hash sometimes can be complex and don't want to ignore.

Key 'k21' can also sometimes have array of hashes.

```
$hash3 = {k1=> { k11 => v1}, k2 => { k21 => [{v3 => v31}, {v2 => v22}] }}
```

How do I compare such complex hash by ignoring the array order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep), which provides `cmp_deeply`. It's a lot more versatile than Test::More's `is_deeply`.

```
use Test::Deep;

my $hash1 = {
    k1 => { k11 => 'v1', k12 => 'v2' }, k2 => { k21 => [ 'v1', 'v2', 'v3' ] } };
my $hash2 = {
    k1 => { k11 => 'v1', k12 => 'v2' }, k2 => { k21 => bag( 'v3', 'v2', 'v1' ) } };

cmp_deeply( $hash1, $hash2, );
```

The trick is the [`bag()` function](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep#bag-elements), which ignores the order of elements.

> This does a bag comparison, that is, it compares two arrays but ignores the order of the elements [...]

---

**Update**: From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135504/perl-compare-two-nested-hash/37135804?noredirect=1#comment61854323_37135804):

> How do I bag all array references inside hash dynamically

Some digging in the code of Test::Deep showed that it's possible to overwrite it. I looked [at Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Test-Deep-1.120/lib/Test/Deep.pm#L135) itself first, and found that there is a [Test::Deep::Array](https://metacpan.org/source/Test::Deep::Array), which deals with arrays. All of the packages that handle stuff inside of T::D have [a `descend` method](https://metacpan.org/source/Test::Deep::Array#L17). So that's where we need to hook in.

[Sub::Override](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override) is great to temporarily override stuff, instead of messing with typeglobs.

Basically all we need to do is replace the call to `Test::Deep::arrayelementsonly` in `Test::Deep::Array::descend`'s final line with a call to `bag()`. The rest is simply copied (indentation is mine). For small [monkey-patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) a copy of the existing code with a slight modification is usually the easiest approach.

```
use Test::Deep;
use Test::Deep::Array;
use Sub::Override;

my $sub = Sub::Override->new(
    'Test::Deep::Array::descend' => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        my $got  = shift;

        my $exp = $self->{val};

        return 0 unless Test::Deep::descend( 
             $got, Test::Deep::arraylength( scalar @$exp ) );

        return 0 unless $self->test_class($got);

        return Test::Deep::descend( $got, Test::Deep::bag(@$exp) );
    }
);

my $hash1 = {
    k1 => { k11 => 'v1', k12 => 'v2' },
    k2 => { k21 => [ 'v1', 'v2', 'v3' ] }
};
my $hash2 = {
    k1 => { k11 => 'v1', k12 => 'v2' },
    k2 => { k21 => [ 'v3', 'v2', 'v1' ] }
};

cmp_deeply( $hash1, $hash2 );
```

This will make the test pass.

**Make sure to reset the override** by undefining `$sub` or letting it go out of scope, or you might have some weird surprises if the rest of your test suite also uses Test::Deep.

Comment: Thanks simbabque for the answer,
How do I bag all array references inside hash dynamically.

$hash2 is output produced and contain nested hash, how do I dynamically say to cmp_deeply that any array comparision should be done via bag, or should I traverse the hash and do individual bag comparisions.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque, How do I bag all array references inside hash dynamically.  
    `my $arr_of_h1 = {'a' => [1, 2 , 3], b => [{2 => 1}, {1 => 1}, {3 => 1}]};`  
    `my $arr_of_h2 = {'a' => [1, 2 , 3], b => [{2 => 1}, {3 => 1}, {1 => 1}]};`
    `cmp_deeply($arr_of_h1->{b}, bag(@{$arr_of_h2->{b}}),"Array are equal");`  
Above stmt works, but want below to work by performing bag comparisons.  
    `cmp_deeply($arr_of_h1, $arr_of_h2,"Hash are equal");`

Comment: @user I think you would have to build that. Or maybe there is some hooking mechanism. Did you read the full Test::Deep docs? Otherwise you can use https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Visitor or something similar to build the traversal. I suggest you ask a new question for that one, as it is different from the initial question here.

Comment: @user see my update. In fact, I had the same problem recently in a test, but decided to change the test case. Figuring this one out was fun.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. With the override I was able to compare 2 complex hashes by ignoring the order of the array.