# how to use foreach loop to do comparison between two arrays of hashes

Tags: perl

i need to use  foreach loop to do comparison between two array of hashes. but I am not really know how to do this .

my original data:

```
NewData(file 1)
Puma
77777 33333 44444 55555 
Adidas
99999 88888 55555 77777 
22222 11111 33333 44444
Brooks
11111 22222 33333 44444 
33333 44444 55555 66666 

OldData(file 2)

Puma
77777 33333 44444 55555 
Adidas
11111 11111 33333 44444 
99999 88888 55555 77777 
Brooks
11111 22222 33333 44444 
33333 44444 55555 66666
```

my hash1:

```
'Adidas' => {
                        'y1' => [
                                  '88888',
                                  '11111'
                                ],
                        'x2' => [
                                  '55555',
                                  '33333'
                                ],
                        'y2' => [
                                  '77777',
                                  '44444'
                                ],
                        'x1' => [
                                  '99999',
                                  '22222'
                                ]
                      },
          'Puma' => {
                      'y1' => [
                                '33333'
                              ],
                      'x2' => [
                                '44444'
                              ],
                      'y2' => [
                                '55555'
                              ],
                      'x1' => [
                                '77777'
                              ]
                    },
 'Brooks' => {
                        'y1' => [
                                  '22222',
                                  '44444'
                                ],
                        'x2' => [
                                  '33333',
                                  '55555'
                                ],
                        'y2' => [
                                  '44444',
                                  '66666'
                                ],
                        'x1' => [
                                  '11111',
                                  '33333'
                                ]
                      }


 };
```

my hash2:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Adidas' => {
                        'y1' => [
                                  '11111',
                                  '88888'
                                ],
                        'x2' => [
                                  '33333',
                                  '55555'
                                ],
                        'y2' => [
                                  '44444',
                                  '77777'
                                ],
                        'x1' => [
                                  '11111',
                                  '99999'
                                ]
                      },
          'Puma' => {
                      'y1' => [
                                '33333'
                              ],
                      'x2' => [
                                '44444'
                              ],
                      'y2' => [
                                '55555'
                              ],
                      'x1' => [
                                '77777'
                              ]
                    },
 'Brooks' => {
                        'y1' => [
                                  '22222',
                                  '44444'
                                ],
                        'x2' => [
                                  '33333',
                                  '55555'
                                ],
                        'y2' => [
                                  '44444',
                                  '66666'
                                ],
                        'x1' => [
                                  '11111',
                                  '33333'
                                ]
                      }
        };
```

my attempt code for matching & non matching:

```
 foreach my $newq (keys %hash1)
    {
         foreach my $oldq(keys %hash2)
         {
         if ( $newq eq $oldq)
         {
         foreach my $newx1(@{$hash1{$newq}{x1}})
         {
         foreach my $oldx1(@{$hash2{$oldq}{x1}})
         {
         if ($newx1 == $oldx1)
         {
         print "$newq\t$newx1\t$oldx1\n";
         }
         if ($newx1 != $oldx1)
         {
         print "$newq\t$newx1\t$oldx1\n";
         }
             }
```

my output for matching

```
         New     Old
Adidas  99999   99999
Puma    77777   77777
Brooks  11111   11111
Brooks  33333   33333
```

My output for non matching :

```
        New     Old
Adidas  99999   11111
Adidas  22222   11111
Adidas  22222   99999
Brooks  11111   33333
Brooks  33333   11111
```

Desired output for matching:

```
                      New                           Old
Puma                77777 33333 44444 55555     77777 33333 44444 55555
Adidas              99999 88888 55555 77777     99999 88888 55555 77777
Brooks              11111 22222 33333 44444     11111 22222 33333 44444
Brooks              33333 44444 55555 66666     33333 44444 55555 66666


Not matching

Adidas              22222 11111 33333 44444     11111 11111 33333 44444
```

Now i can get the correct matching for x1. But i get the wrong output for 'non matching' . my expected output for 'non matching' is `Adidas              22222 11111` only  because `'x1=> 99999'` is presented in both new data and old data. And i am not sure how to continue with the 'y1, x2, and y2' ...

Comment: keys of the hashes are always same or can be different, because here i see keys in both the cases keys are same and you are just trying to compare the values of x1,y1 etc. and also i don't think u need 2 seperated foreach loops for matching and non matching, u can just use flags and do it in same loop but better to use Data:Compare as suggested by @MattJacob

Comment: Why can't you use the [Data::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Compare) module?

Comment: you can visit this link for similar answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273616/how-do-i-compare-two-hashes-in-perl-without-using-datacompare

Comment: I haven't learn about the Data::Compare . As  i thought this only can be done by using foreach loop to compare x1 to x1, y1 to y1 independently . @MattJacob

Comment: Yeah, actually my idea was using 1 foreach loop to do the matching and non matching. i wrote 2 foreach loops on above just want to let ppl  know that i only make  a small changes from ($newx1 == $oldx1) to ($newx1 != $oldx1). i'll make correction on it .@NileshJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x1, y1 etc... are just keys in a hash so you can get them the same way you get the keys any hash like this

```
keys %{$hash1{$newq}}
```

You don't need to make your code as complicated as you have though with all those many layers of loops. Take this part for example...

```
foreach my $newq (keys %hash1)
{
     foreach my $oldq(keys %hash2)
     {
         if ( $newq eq $oldq)
         {
             # ....
         }
     }
 }
```

You don't need to loop through both hashes because you can test to see if a key exists in the other hash. Imagine if your hashes had 100 keys each. Your code currently checks all 100 keys in `%hash2` with each key in `%hash1` and then does it again, so 20000 tests. If you write the code like this...

```
foreach my $newq (keys %hash1)
{
    if(defined($hash2{$newq}))
    {
        # both hashes have this key
    }
    else
    {
        # %hash2 doesn't have the key
    }
}

foreach my $newq (keys %hash2)
{
    if(!defined($hash1{$newq}))
    {
        # %hash1 doesn't have the key
    }
    else
    {
        # They both do, but we already know that from the first loop
    }
}
```

...it only has to check each key in the two hashes once so just 200 checks.

So ultimately the finished code could be:

```
my %nonmatching;
print "Matching\n";
foreach my $outerkey (keys %hash1)
{
    if(defined($hash2{$outerkey}))
    {
        foreach my $innerkey (keys %{$hash1{$outerkey}})
        {
            if(join(" ",sort @{$hash1{$outerkey}{$innerkey}}) eq join(" ",sort @{$hash2{$outerkey}{$innerkey}}))
            {
                 printf "%-20s %30s %30s\n",$outerkey, join(" ",@{$hash1{$outerkey}{$innerkey}}), join(" ",@{$hash2{$outerkey}{$innerkey}});
            } 
            else
            {
                 $nonmatching{$outerkey}{$innerkey}=1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach my $innerkey (keys %{$hash1{$outerkey}})
        {
            $nonmatching{$outerkey}{$innerkey}=1;
        }
    }
}

foreach my $outerkey (keys %hash2)
{
    if(!defined($hash1{$outerkey}))
    {
        foreach my $innerkey (keys %{$hash2{$outerkey}})
        {
            $nonmatching{$outerkey}{$innerkey}=1;
        }
    }
}

print "Nonmatching\n";
foreach my $outerkey (keys %nonmatching)
{
    foreach my $innerkey (keys %{$nonmatching{$outerkey}})
    {
         printf "%-20s %30s %30s\n",$outerkey, join(" ",@{$hash1{$outerkey}{$innerkey}}), join(" ",@{$hash2{$outerkey}{$innerkey}});
    }
}
```

Although the hashes as you've declared them don't match up with your source data, so the output doesn't look how you'd expect. I'd have expected your hashes would look more like the below snippet, so maybe your file reading code isn't working as you want it too?

```
'Adidas' => {
   'x1' => [
       '99999','88888','55555','77777'
    ]
  };
```